# how to specify the gradle local.properties path in command line param?

Tags: gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I hope to build my android app in both windows and WSL(win10's ubuntu),

but with the same `local.properties` file, it can't provide different style of path corresponding to each OS.

so I want to have two `local.properties` for each other and specify one in command line param, how could this be done?